# Windows Phone 8: Monitoring memory usage in mixed C#/C++

Tags: c#, c++, memory-management, code-analysis, windows-phone-8

I want to monitor memory usage of a mixed C#/C++ app on Windows Phone 8 which uses Windows Phone Runtime Components. The problem is that when openening the analysis toolkit in Visual Studio (ALT+F1) I have only the option "Execution" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202934%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). For "pure" C# project the memory options are available as well.

Are there other more or less easy means to monitor memory usage?

Regards,

Comment: `void ShowCsharpMemUsage() {std::cout <<"All your RAM are belong to us!."}`

Comment: How does this "constructive" comment help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered building your own C# memory monitoring UI? It won't be as fancy or detailed as Visual Studio's memory analyzer, but it was the norm for about a year before WP7.5 introduced memory profiling capability.

I've written about this topic before on Nokia's Wiki under [Techniques for memory analysis of Windows Phone apps](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Techniques_for_memory_analysis_of_Windows_Phone_apps#Add_on-screen_coding4fun_.3CMemoryCounter_.2F.3E). Specifically the parts you care about are [Add on-screen coding4fun MemoryCounter](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Techniques_for_memory_analysis_of_Windows_Phone_apps#Add_on-screen_coding4fun_.3CMemoryCounter_.2F.3E) and [Create your own memory profiler](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Techniques_for_memory_analysis_of_Windows_Phone_apps#Create_your_own_memory_profiler).

Comment: Thanks for the Wiki article. I have changed the output to a csv format for easier analysis with Matlab (or Excel).

Comment: @JustinAngel Someone here suggests unload the C++ project http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-us/5f430552-0b75-40da-9de2-664ba3fb9a74/cannot-select-memory-profiling-for-my-wp8-application But from what I see in the profiling log, there is no info about C++ objects