# How to perform memory profiling WP C++ runtime component?

Tags: memory, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, profiling, components

I want to perform memory profiling my Windows Phone 8 Runtime Component. Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13864426/windows-phone-8-monitoring-memory-usage-in-mixed-c-c) and [this workaround](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-us/5f430552-0b75-40da-9de2-664ba3fb9a74/cannot-select-memory-profiling-for-my-wp8-application), I can select Memory Profiling mode in Windows Phone application analysis.

However, it only shows information about C# object. My WP Runtime component contains some C++ libraries that could potentially cause memory leaks. How to perform memory profiling WP runtime component ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Phone 8: Monitoring memory usage in mixed C#/C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13864426/windows-phone-8-monitoring-memory-usage-in-mixed-c-c)